# Accessing JSON variable on javascript

Tags: javascript, json

newbie question.... I have a JSON variable which I do not know how to access it...
Here is the thing:

```
console.log(userChatsHeaders);
Object {
  "chats": Array [
    Object {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": "6017c9644f0d554450007a89",
      "archived": false,
      "created": "2021-01-24T14:52:11.160Z",
      "description": "",
      "members": Array [],
      "messages": null,
      "name": "South Korea",
      "owner": Array [],
      "password": "",
      "tipus": "group",
    },
  ],
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(userChatsHeaders));
{"chats":[{"archived":false,"owner":[],"members":[],"_id":"6017c9644f0d554450007a89","tipus":"group","name":"South Korea","description":"","password":"","created":"2021-01-24T14:52:11.160Z","__v":0,"messages":null}]}
```

then :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(userChatsHeaders[0]));
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userChatsHeaders[0]')
```

and :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(userChatsHeaders.chats[0].tipus));
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userChatsHeaders.chats')

console.log(JSON.stringify(userChatsHeaders.tipus)); 
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userChatsHeaders.tipus')
```

How to access "tipus"?

Comment: `{"chats"` — You can't ignore the object the array is contained in and pretend that `userChatsHeaders` is the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

json_var -> chats -> [0] -> tipus

since the obj in whihc the tipus is stored in an array, it would be easier if you would just iterate over the chats array.

```
chats = userChatsHeaders.chats
chats.forEach(c => {
    console.log(c.tipus)
})
```

Comment: I get : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userChatsHeaders.chats')

Comment: `let d = {
    "chats": [{
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "6017c9644f0d554450007a89",
        "archived": false,
        "created": "2021-01-24T14:52:11.160Z",
        "description": "",
        "members": [],
        "messages": null,
        "name": "South Korea",
        "owner": [],
        "password": "",
        "tipus": "group",
    }, ],
}

chats = d.chats
chats.forEach(c => {
    console.log(c.tipus)
})`
Output:
group

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the data from server, then you need parse the json string and use the following to accesss "tipus"

```
var jsonString = '{"chats":[{"archived":false,"owner":[],"members":[],"_id":"6017c9644f0d554450007a89","tipus":"group","name":"South Korea","description":"","password":"","created":"2021-01-24T14:52:11.160Z","__v":0,"messages":null}]}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(jsonObject.chats[0].tipus);
```

if you already have json object simply access using `console.log(jsonObject.chats[0].tipus);`

Comment: userChatsHeaders is already an object, check updated question logs